# Drawbacks of using ionic with angularjs in comparison to native app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

ok hybrid apps are the new cool story 2015. But what are the drawbacks compared to a native app?

performance is one. A browser will never run as smoothly as a native app.

?running background service on startup? (probably, since the browser is not started on boot up, e.g. receiving notifications in whatsapp style seems impossible without the app being open)

?offline usage? (can I basically boot up the app offline, without loading any html etc over the net?)

?what else?

is there an alternative to ionic that addresses these issues?

**EDIT**

would it eventually be possible to use a service that boots up along side the app? e.g. you install the ionic app, and with it comes a native service that gets added later?

Comment: dear scrum masters, if you vote for close, please state why. "Too broad" is not a reason

Answer (score 2):

In the book [Ionic in Action](http://amzn.to/1OmROE4), the author Jeremy Wilken says this about the hybrid mobile app disadvantages:

> Hybrid apps have a few disadvantages due to the restrictions that are placed on WebViews and limitations of native integrations:
>
> - WebView limitations — The application can only run as well as the WebView instance, which means performance is tied to the quality of the platform’s browser.
> - Access native features via plugins — Access to the native APIs you need may not be currently available, and may require additional development to make a plugin to support it.
> - No native user interface controls — Without a tool like Ionic, developers would have to create all of the user interface elements.

If you have a lot of items in a list, scrolling will suffer (true, this was improved by `collection-repeat`, but it's a fact still if we're being nitpicky)

Clearly, if you're trying to build a game, not to mention a 3D game, then you shouldn't be considering hybrid mobile apps at all. Unity3D in that case (from my personal experience) is the road you may want to take.

To answer you on the question of offline usage - sure, you can use your app offline, if of course you designed it like that so that you don't need a constant Internet connection. For example, in my [4 part tutorial series](http://blog.pluralsight.com/ionic-framework-on-mac-and-windows) which I wrote for Pluralsight I show you how to create a simple calculator application and deploy it to the App/Play stores, and this app for example doesn't need any internet connection. There's a [free book](https://leanpub.com/ionic-framework) also, in case you're interested.

One of the ideas for solving the issue when you do (and don't have) is to save everything locally and upon getting the connection synchronizing what was saved during the offline period. Clearly, this isn't as simple as it sounds and it would take you some time to do right, but regarding viability, it's definitely possible.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I understand, native features are offered via plugins, BUT: the background service app can never run on bootup, because that would mean the whole browser must startup, to finally call the plugin, right? Or do I miss something? so this will never come, but is quite important imho. A plugin runs when called by the ionic app, but cannot get installed into the startup separately imho

Comment: I have to be honest here and say that I don't quite understand what you exactly mean - could you provide an example? I mean, generally, if your app requires some data initially as the app starts from some external API and you don't have the internet connection - your app should handle that in terms of saying something like "app requires internet connection to run".

Comment: ok think of this: you turn off your phone -> then you turn on your phone. Say there is internet. Fresh phone start so. My ionic app is not started yet, agree? To receive notifications of my app, there must be something running though, agree? I cannot send messages from my server to the user having installed my app, but who is not running it, right. For example, whatsapp, facebook, start a small background service on phone startup. This background service will look for messages even if the user did not start the app. Otherwise you would have to start the phone, then _manually_ start whatsapp.

Comment: how can I start a background service like this using ionic? I fear, I guess: i cannot.

Comment: Ok, now I understand you perfectly, but unfortunately I don't know how to do this. Interesting question though.